# One SQL count query

Tags: sql, flask, count

I have made 4 separate queries mainly for counting. It works, but it would be much simpler both in sql and later in flask/jinja to have one query. Is this achievable?

```
        SELECT users.id AS id,
        registration_date,
        login
        FROM users
        ORDER BY id;


        SELECT users.id AS id,
        count(question.id) as question_number
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN question ON question.user_id = users.id
        GROUP BY users.id
        ORDER BY id;


        SELECT users.id AS id,
        count(answer.id) as answer_number
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN  answer ON answer.user_id = users.id
        GROUP BY users.id
        ORDER BY id;


        SELECT users.id AS id,
        count(comment.id) as comment_number
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN comment ON comment.user_id = users.id
        GROUP BY users.id
        ORDER BY id;
```

I tried this (of course with no success):

```
        SELECT users.id AS id,
        registration_date,
        login
        count(question.id) as question_number
        count(answer.id) as answer_number,
        count(comment.id) as comment_number
        FROM users
        INNER JOIN question ON question.user_id = users.id
        INNER JOIN answer ON answer.user_id = users.id
        INNER JOIN comment ON comment.user_id = users.id
        GROUP BY users.id, registration_date, login 
        ORDER BY id
```

Comment: You could GROUP BY in subqueries _before_ joining. Or simply put _correlated subqueries_ in the select list.

Comment: Why wasn't your attempt success? Also have you tried COUNT(DISTINCT question.id)?

Comment: You are right - DISTINCT - solved the problem! Before numbers were much higher then expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    u.id AS id,
    u.registration_date,
    u.login,
    q.question_number,
    a.answer_number,
    c.comment_number
FROM 
    users u
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS question_number 
     FROM question 
     GROUP BY user_id) q ON q.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS answer_number 
     FROM answer 
     GROUP BY user_id) a ON a.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS comment_number 
     FROM comment 
     GROUP BY user_id) c ON c.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY 
    u.id;
```

Comment: A good answer *explains* the solution, it doesn't just dump code.